# .NET RegEx set group value by name

Tags: .net, regex

I have a RegEx like this: `Age range (?<AGESTART>\d{1,2})-(?<AGEEND>\d{1,2})`

I received from the user the values for `AGESTART` (let's say `20`) and `AGEEND` (let's say `30`).

How can I get a string, replacing the `AGESTART` and `AGEEND` capturing groups with the values I already know?

I know I can work with String `substring`/`replace`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way like `RegEx.Replace("AGESTART", 20)` and `RegEx.Replace("AGEEND", 30)`. Ideally I don't want to manipulate the RegEx as string, but as a Regular Expression.

Comment: Why do you need a regex pattern at the first place? Just use `var pattern = string.Format("Age range {0}-{1}", 20, 30);`.

Comment: @stribizhev The RegEx is used in other places, for matching some data. And now I need to replace the groups with the information, and wanted to use some RegEx function for that.

Comment: So, you want to replace a part of an already compiled regex pattern? It is not possible without recompiling the regex object.

Comment: @stribizhev No, I don't want to replace the RegEx pattern, but extract a matching string substituting the groups with values I already have. The RegEx.Replace almost works, but it asks for the whole string, not just group's values.

Comment: I do not see any practical purpose. What do you need to do? Something like [this](http://ideone.com/D7NKJY)?

Comment: @igorjrr Are they replaced with the same value or different values?

Comment: @igorjrr I ask because it's easy to perform the same operation on each value, but harder to make two unique operations.  Can you give some exact use cases?

Comment: @stribizhev I need to produce an input string, from the regular expression, and knowing the group values. What you showed is almost there, but all I have is the pattern and the group values (in your example you had to input part of the pattern ('Age range' many times).

Comment: I typed `'Age range'` by hand because I thought it was a static part of a string. Try [this](http://ideone.com/LXKJUw) and please update the question with what you have and what you need to obtain.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of captures: they are meant to *store*/*keep* some subtexts, not to replace them. You only capture what you need to keep.

Comment: @stribizhev I was able to do what I needed by using RegEx against a regular expression, to substitute the groups with the values I have. See my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` objects contain exactly zero state having to do with your inputs. This is good, because it means that a `Regex` object can be used across many inputs, even on many threads, all without trouble.

You seem to want `Regex` to remember what string it last processed, and then perform replacements on that string according to the match groups. No such methods could exist in `Regex` because it would violate the design of `Regex` - statelessness. When you apply an input to a `Regex` object, the state for that application is either stored on the stack, and thrown out (`myRegex.IsMatch( text )`), or is saved and returned in a `Match` object.

You can perform replacements using `Match`, but not in the manner you desire:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.result%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = "--(.+?)--";
      string replacement = "($1)";
      string input = "He said--decisively--that the time--whatever time it was--had come.";
      foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
      {
         string result = match.Result(replacement);
         Console.WriteLine(result);
      }
   }
}

// The example displays the following output:
//       (decisively)
//       (whatever time it was)
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute each group with the values already stored in a Dictionary object:

http://ideone.com/ZFVoQX

```
        Dim MyDictionary as New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        MyDictionary.Add("AGESTART", "20")
        MyDictionary.Add("AGEEND", "30")
        Dim originalRegEx as String = "Age range (?<AGESTART>\d{1,2})-(?<AGEEND>\d{1,2})"
        Dim filledRegEx as String = originalRegEx
        Dim re As Regex = New Regex("\(\?\<(?<GROUPNAME>.*?)>.*?\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        For Each m As Match In re.Matches(filledRegEx)
              filledRegEx = Replace(filledRegEx, m.Value, MyDictionary(m.Groups("GROUPNAME").Value))
        Next
```